# Libgdx input processor doesn't work properly

Tags: java, input, libgdx, touch

I have this game which follows on every input the player makes in the game. I defined specific actions for touchDragged,touchDown and touchUp. The only problem is that whenever the player starts to move his mouse/finger and then stops but still keeps his mouse/finger down, the game doesn't catch that input and as a result the game doesn't work properly.

Is there any way to process input in case the user drags the finger/mouse and then stops without lifting his finger?

Here his my InputProcessor:

```
package com.david.helpers;

import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.david.objects.Acorn;

public class InputHandler implements InputProcessor{

    private Vector2 target;
    private Vector3 temp;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Array<Acorn> acorns;
    private boolean isAiming = false;

    public InputHandler(Array<Acorn> acorns, OrthographicCamera camera) {
        this.camera = camera;
        this.acorns = acorns;
        target = new Vector2();
        temp = new Vector3();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.unproject(temp.set(screenX, screenY, 0));
        if(!temp.isZero() && temp != null) {
            target.set(temp.x, temp.y);
            target.sub(acorns.peek().getBody().getPosition());
            target.nor();
            isAiming = true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.unproject(temp.set(screenX, screenY, 0));
        if(!temp.isZero() && temp != null) {
            target.set(temp.x, temp.y);
            target.sub(acorns.peek().getBody().getPosition());
            target.nor();
            acorns.peek().getBody().setLinearVelocity(target.cpy().scl(25));
            isAiming = false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.unproject(temp.set(screenX, screenY, 0));
        if(!temp.isZero() && temp != null) {
            target.set(temp.x, temp.y);
            target.sub(acorns.peek().getBody().getPosition());
            target.nor();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    public Vector2 getTarget() {
        return this.target;
    }
    public boolean isAiming() {
        return this.isAiming;
    }
}
```

My problem behind this is pretty simple - I have a projectile that before it is launched, the user can drag the mouse/finger and choose where to fire it. Now, the code draws a trajectory according to the user touch and it works fine. The only problem is that whenever the user stops moving his finger but still keeps it down, the program doesn't draw the trajectory. In my Renderer class I check if the isAiming variable from the InputProcessor is true. If so, it draws the desired trajectory.
As I see it, it's like the InputProcessor doesn't get touch data on that specific moment, when the user starts to move around his finger and then stops his movement but still keeps it down.

This is very annoying and I would be happy if you guys could help me out here :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, touches in Android devices are often buggy. For what you want, try [Input Polling](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Polling) instead:

```
//In your render method.
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
    camera.unproject(temp.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
    if(!temp.isZero() && temp != null) {
        target.set(temp.x, temp.y);
        target.sub(acorns.peek().getBody().getPosition());
        target.nor();
        isAiming = true;
    }
}else{
    if(isAiming){
        camera.unproject(temp.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
        if(!temp.isZero() && temp != null) {
            target.set(temp.x, temp.y);
            target.sub(acorns.peek().getBody().getPosition());
            target.nor();
            acorns.peek().getBody().setLinearVelocity(target.cpy().scl(25));
            isAiming = false;
        }
    }
}
```